# Unable to import pg_dump as the PostgreSQL Docker containter initdb

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile

I have a postgres dump and I want to create a docker container that with the database from the dump. For the purposes of this Question it is fine that the container loads it on every startup.

So my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV PGDATA=/data

COPY ./dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Which succesfully builds, however starting the container gives this error:

```
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql:19: ERROR:  relation "public.max_designation" does not exist
```

What confuses me, it that starting the container and importing manually via this script works fine:

```
docker run --name PG_LOCAL -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -d postgres
cat ./dump.sql| docker exec -i PG_LOCAL psql -U postgres
```

**So why does it only fail when starting the container but manually importing the data is fine?**

The dump looks like this:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 11.17
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.17

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.max_designation DROP CONSTRAINT max_designation_transportnoticearticle_id_fkey;
[...]
```

Comment: 1) Add the complete `pg_dump` command used to create `dump/sql` to your question. 2) Does the dump file actually start the DDL section `ALTER TABLE ONLY public.max_designation`? If that is the case I don't see how it could work unless `public.max_designation` already existed in the database.

Comment: Sadly I currently do not have access to the command that created the dump. And yes, those are the first lines of the dump unedited. I will try to get another dump and see if that works.

Comment: Then someone has been editing the dump, as I don't know of a way `pg_dump` will produce that output on its own.